# Why is the block cropped at small screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css

Why does the block get cropped at small screen resolutions? I have a picture and a background with a minimum width, but even if I change it to a minimum, nothing works

Code https://jsfiddle.net/sxn05j7k/

I done

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4zln.jpg)

right

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n0yf.jpg)

Site ilyin1ib.beget.tech

```js
jQuery(($) => {
    const selectSingle = document.querySelector('.__select');
    const selectSingle_title = selectSingle.querySelector('.__select__title');
    const selectSingle_span = selectSingle.querySelector('.__select__title > span');
    const selectSingle_labels = selectSingle.querySelectorAll('.__select__label');

    
    selectSingle_title.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if ('active' === selectSingle.getAttribute('data-state')) {
            selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', '');
        } else {
            selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', 'active');
        }
    });

    
    for (let i = 0; i < selectSingle_labels.length; i++) {
        selectSingle_labels[i].addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
            const {
                alt,
                src
            } = evt.currentTarget.querySelector('img')
            
            const imgNode = selectSingle.querySelector('img')

            imgNode.alt = alt
            imgNode.src = src

            selectSingle_span.textContent = evt.currentTarget.textContent

            selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', '')
        });
    }


    $(".phone_mask").mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");

});
```

```css
html,
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1280px;
    padding: 40px 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 24px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.col {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.img {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    background: url(../img/big-bg.png) center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    min-width: 560px;
}

.img img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 42px;
    margin: auto;
}

.img-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
}


h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 40px !important;
}

.img span {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 0 40px 40px;
}


.form-block {
    text-align: center;
}

.title {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #212121;
}

form {
    padding: 50px 100px !important;
}

label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.green {
    color: #428A60;
}


input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;

}

input::placeholder {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.phone-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}


.phone-block input {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.number {
    margin-right: 20px;
}


button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    background: #428A60;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button i {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #3BC374;
    color: #000;
}


.__select {
    position: relative;
    width: 118px;
    height: 47px;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__title::before {
    transform: translate(-3px, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__title::after {
    transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__content {
    opacity: 1;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__label+.__select__input+.__select__label {
    max-height: 40px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
}

.__select__title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

.__select__title::before,
.__select__title::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    background-color: #333;
    transform: translate(-3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.__select__title::after {
    transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.__select__title:hover {
    border-color: #428A60;
}

.__select__title:hover::before,
.__select__title:hover::after {
    background-color: #428A60;
}

.reset {
    display: flex;
    width: 230px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #c7ccd1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

.reset:hover {
    background-color: #428A60;
    color: #fff;
}

.__select__content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #c7ccd1;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 8;
}

.__select__input {
    display: none;
}

.__select__input:checked+label {
    background-color: #dedede;
}

.__select__input:disabled+label {
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.__select__label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0 16px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.__select__label+input+.__select__label {
    border-top: 0 solid #c7ccd1 60;
}

.__select__label:hover {
    background-color: #428A60 !important;
    color: #fff;
}

.flag span {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.flag img {
    width: 26px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.secure {
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    width: 339px;
}

.secure i {
    color: #428A60;
    padding: 10px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    input {
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }

    .title {
        background-color: #F8F8F8;
        padding: 20px 80px;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .img {
        min-width: 460px;
    }


    h1 {
        padding: 20px !important;
    }

    .img span {

        padding: 0 0 20px 20px !important;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1220px) {
    .phone_mask {
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1220px) {
    .phone_mask {
        padding: 15px 5px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .wrapper {
        height:  auto;
    }
    .item {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 40px;
    }

    .col {
        width: auto;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .img {
        background: url(../img/min-bg.png) center no-repeat;
        background-size: 82%;
        min-height: 430px;
    }


    .img img {
        position: static;
        width: 80%;
    }

    .img-info {
        position: static;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    h1, .img span {
        padding: 0 !important;
        color: #212121 !important;
    }


    .title {
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 40px
    }


    form {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

    .number {
        margin-right: 10px
    }

    .phone_mask {
        padding: 15px 20px;
    }

    .secure {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .img {
        background-size: 82%;
        min-height: 430px;
    }


    .img img {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .img {
        background-size: 72%;
        min-height: 360px;
        min-width: 320px;
    }

    .img img {
        width: 70%;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .img {
        min-height: 350px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .img {
        min-height: 320px;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 630px) {
    .img {
        min-height: 300px;
        background-size: 67%;
    }

    .img img {
        width: 65%;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 630px) {
    .img {
        min-height: 290px;
        background-size: 67%;
    }

    .img img {
        width: 65%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 630px) {
    .img {
        min-height: 290px;
        background-size: 67%;
    }

    .img img {
        width: 65%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 560px) {
   .img {
       min-height: 280px;
   }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8e0bceeac7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/clear.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/adaptive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.maskedinput@1.4.1/src/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Редуслим</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col img">
                <div class="img-info">
                    <h1>Reduslim</h1>
                    <span>eco</span>
                </div>
                <img src="img/tablets.webp" alt="tablets">
            </div>
            <div class="col form-block">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Сделай шаг<br>к выздоровлению</h2>
                </div>
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <label for="name">ваше <span class="green">имя</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_name" required id="name" placeholder="Алексей">
                    <div class="phone-block">
                        <div class="number">
                            <label for="phone">ваш <span class="green">телефон</span></label>
                            <input class="phone_mask" type="tel" name="user_phone" required id="phone" placeholder="+7 (123) 456 78-90">
                        </div>
                        <div class="__select" data-state="">
                            <div class="__select__title flag" data-default="Option 0">
                                <span>RU</span>
                                <img src="img/ru.svg" alt="ru">
                            </div>
                            <div class="__select__content">
                                <input id="singleSelect0" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" checked />
                                <label for="singleSelect0" class="__select__label">
                                </label>
                                <input id="singleSelect1" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                                <label for="singleSelect1" class="__select__label flag">
                                    <span>GR</span>
                                    <img src="img/gr.svg" alt="gr">
                                </label>
                                <input id="singleSelect3" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                                <label for="singleSelect3" class="__select__label flag">
                                    <span>UK</span>
                                    <img src="img/uk.svg" alt="">
                                </label>
                                <input id="singleSelect4" class="__select__input flag" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                                <label for="singleSelect4" class="__select__label flag">
                                    <span>RU</span>
                                    <img src="img/ru.svg" alt="ru">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button>Заказать<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="secure">
    <span>Trusted</span>
    <span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
    <span>Secure</span>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code here. Feel free to keep the Jsfiddle link available for people, but having the code in your question will help others to help you.

Comment: i don't have a solid answer for you but it appears that `justify-content: center` which might be messing you up on screen resolutions that are wider than the content.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because your `<div class="secure">` has fixed width: `width: 339px;`.

Replace it with `width: 100%;` and `max-width: 339px;` and block will not crop anymore.

```js
jQuery(($) => {
    const selectSingle = document.querySelector('.__select');
    const selectSingle_title = selectSingle.querySelector('.__select__title');
    const selectSingle_span = selectSingle.querySelector('.__select__title > span');
    const selectSingle_labels = selectSingle.querySelectorAll('.__select__label');

    
    selectSingle_title.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if ('active' === selectSingle.getAttribute('data-state')) {
            selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', '');
        } else {
            selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', 'active');
        }
    });

    
    for (let i = 0; i < selectSingle_labels.length; i++) {
        selectSingle_labels[i].addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
            const {
                alt,
                src
            } = evt.currentTarget.querySelector('img')
            
            const imgNode = selectSingle.querySelector('img')

            imgNode.alt = alt
            imgNode.src = src

            selectSingle_span.textContent = evt.currentTarget.textContent

            selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', '')
        });
    }


    $(".phone_mask").mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");

});
```

```css
html,
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1280px;
    padding: 40px 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 24px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.col {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.img {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    background: url(../img/big-bg.png) center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    min-width: 560px;
}

.img img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 42px;
    margin: auto;
}

.img-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
}


h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 40px !important;
}

.img span {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 0 40px 40px;
}


.form-block {
    text-align: center;
}

.title {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #212121;
}

form {
    padding: 50px 100px !important;
}

label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.green {
    color: #428A60;
}


input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;

}

input::placeholder {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.phone-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}


.phone-block input {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.number {
    margin-right: 20px;
}


button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    background: #428A60;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button i {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #3BC374;
    color: #000;
}


.__select {
    position: relative;
    width: 118px;
    height: 47px;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__title::before {
    transform: translate(-3px, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__title::after {
    transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__content {
    opacity: 1;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__label+.__select__input+.__select__label {
    max-height: 40px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
}

.__select__title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

.__select__title::before,
.__select__title::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    background-color: #333;
    transform: translate(-3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.__select__title::after {
    transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.__select__title:hover {
    border-color: #428A60;
}

.__select__title:hover::before,
.__select__title:hover::after {
    background-color: #428A60;
}

.reset {
    display: flex;
    width: 230px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #c7ccd1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

.reset:hover {
    background-color: #428A60;
    color: #fff;
}

.__select__content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #c7ccd1;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 8;
}

.__select__input {
    display: none;
}

.__select__input:checked+label {
    background-color: #dedede;
}

.__select__input:disabled+label {
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.__select__label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0 16px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.__select__label+input+.__select__label {
    border-top: 0 solid #c7ccd1 60;
}

.__select__label:hover {
    background-color: #428A60 !important;
    color: #fff;
}

.flag span {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.flag img {
    width: 26px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.secure {
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    /*width: 339px;*/
    max-width: 339px;
    width: 100%;
}

.secure i {
    color: #428A60;
    padding: 10px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    input {
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }

    .title {
        background-color: #F8F8F8;
        padding: 20px 80px;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .img {
        min-width: 460px;
    }


    h1 {
        padding: 20px !important;
    }

    .img span {

        padding: 0 0 20px 20px !important;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1220px) {
    .phone_mask {
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1220px) {
    .phone_mask {
        padding: 15px 5px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .wrapper {
        height:  auto;
    }
    .item {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 40px;
    }

    .col {
        width: auto;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .img {
        background: url(../img/min-bg.png) center no-repeat;
        background-size: 82%;
        min-height: 430px;
    }


    .img img {
        position: static;
        width: 80%;
    }

    .img-info {
        position: static;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    h1, .img span {
        padding: 0 !important;
        color: #212121 !important;
    }


    .title {
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 40px
    }


    form {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

    .number {
        margin-right: 10px
    }

    .phone_mask {
        padding: 15px 20px;
    }

    .secure {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .img {
        background-size: 82%;
        min-height: 430px;
    }


    .img img {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .img {
        background-size: 72%;
        min-height: 360px;
        min-width: 320px;
    }

    .img img {
        width: 70%;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .img {
        min-height: 350px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .img {
        min-height: 320px;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 630px) {
    .img {
        min-height: 300px;
        background-size: 67%;
    }

    .img img {
        width: 65%;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 630px) {
    .img {
        min-height: 290px;
        background-size: 67%;
    }

    .img img {
        width: 65%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 630px) {
    .img {
        min-height: 290px;
        background-size: 67%;
    }

    .img img {
        width: 65%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 560px) {
   .img {
       min-height: 280px;
   }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8e0bceeac7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/clear.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/adaptive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.maskedinput@1.4.1/src/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Редуслим</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col img">
                <div class="img-info">
                    <h1>Reduslim</h1>
                    <span>eco</span>
                </div>
                <img src="img/tablets.webp" alt="tablets">
            </div>
            <div class="col form-block">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Сделай шаг<br>к выздоровлению</h2>
                </div>
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <label for="name">ваше <span class="green">имя</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_name" required id="name" placeholder="Алексей">
                    <div class="phone-block">
                        <div class="number">
                            <label for="phone">ваш <span class="green">телефон</span></label>
                            <input class="phone_mask" type="tel" name="user_phone" required id="phone" placeholder="+7 (123) 456 78-90">
                        </div>
                        <div class="__select" data-state="">
                            <div class="__select__title flag" data-default="Option 0">
                                <span>RU</span>
                                <img src="img/ru.svg" alt="ru">
                            </div>
                            <div class="__select__content">
                                <input id="singleSelect0" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" checked />
                                <label for="singleSelect0" class="__select__label">
                                </label>
                                <input id="singleSelect1" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                                <label for="singleSelect1" class="__select__label flag">
                                    <span>GR</span>
                                    <img src="img/gr.svg" alt="gr">
                                </label>
                                <input id="singleSelect3" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                                <label for="singleSelect3" class="__select__label flag">
                                    <span>UK</span>
                                    <img src="img/uk.svg" alt="">
                                </label>
                                <input id="singleSelect4" class="__select__input flag" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                                <label for="singleSelect4" class="__select__label flag">
                                    <span>RU</span>
                                    <img src="img/ru.svg" alt="ru">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button>Заказать<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="secure">
    <span>Trusted</span>
    <span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
    <span>Secure</span>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i fixed it but it didn't help